# How to pass current object inside ng-repeat to $mdDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Dialog should include details of currently selected product. How to make it work?

At the moment this doesn't work: `<h2>Order: {{product.name}}</h2>`

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ResilientJoe/pen/VaQvYZ?editors=1010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `locals` property:

In `ng-click` add the product:

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAdvanced($event, product)">
```

In the Dialog pass it as `locals`:

```
$mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'orderDialog.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      fullscreen: useFullScreen,
      locals:{dataToPass: product},
    })
```

In the Controller assign it to the `scope`:

```
var mdDialogCtrl = function ($scope, dataToPass) { 
    $scope.product = dataToPass  
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGyKag?editors=1010) updated